# Don't you get a random number after doing modulo on a hashed number?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to understand hash tables, and from what I've seen the modulo operator is used to select which bucket a key will be placed in. I know that hash algorithms are supposed to minimize the same result for different inputs, however I don't understand how the same results for different inputs can be minimal after the modulo operation. Let's just say we have a near-perfect hash function that gives a different hashed value between 0 and 100,000, and then we take the result modulo 20 (in our example we have 20 buckets), isn't the resulting number very close to a random number between 0 and 19? Meaning roughly the probability that the final result is any of a number between 0 and 19 is about 1 in 20? If this is the case, then the original hash function doesn't seem to ensure minimal collisions because after the modulo operation we end up with something like a random number? I must be wrong, but I'm thinking that what ensures minimal collisions the most is not the original hash function but how many buckets we have.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding this. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

> Don't you get a random number after doing modulo on a hashed number?

It depends on the hash function.

Say you have an identify hash for numbers - h(n) = n - then if the keys being hashed are generally incrementing numbers (perhaps with an occasional ommision), then after hashing they'll still generally hit successive buckets (wrapping at some point from the last bucket back to the first), with low collision rates overall.  Not very random, but works out well enough.  If the keys are random, it still works out pretty well - see the discussion of random-but-repeatable hashing below.  The problem is when the keys are neither roughly-incrementing nor close-to-random - then an identity hash can provide terrible collision rates.  (You might think "this is a crazy bad example hash function, nobody would do this; actually, most C++ Standard Library implementations' hash functions for integers are identity hashes).

On the other hand, if you have a hash function that say takes the address of the object being hashed, and they're all 8 byte aligned, then if you take the mod and the bucket count is also a multiple of 8, you'll only ever hash to every 8th bucket, having 8 times more collisions than you might expect.  Not very random, and doesn't work out well.  But, if the number of buckets is a prime, then the addresses will tend to scatter much more randomly over the buckets, and things will work out much better.  This is the reason the GNU C++ Standard Library tends to use prime numbers of buckets (Visual C++ uses power-of-two sized buckets so it can utilise a bitwise AND for mapping hash values to buckets, as AND takes one CPU cycle and MOD can take e.g. 30-40 cycles - depending on your exact CPU - see [here](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)).

When all the inputs are known at compile time, and there's not too many of them, then it's generally possible to create a perfect hash function (GNU gperf software is designed specifically for this), which means it will work out a number of buckets you'll need and a hash function that avoids any collisions, but the hash function may take longer to run than a general purpose function.

People often have a fanciful notion - also seen in the question - that a "perfect hash function" - or at least one that has very few collisions - in some large numerical hashed-to range will provide minimal collisions in actual usage in a hash table, as indeed this stackoverflow question is about coming to grips with the falsehood of this notion.  It's just not true if there are still patterns and probabilities in the way the keys map into that large hashed-to range.

The gold standard for a general purpose high-quality hash function for runtime inputs is to have a quality that you might call *"random but repeatable"*, even before the modulo operation, as that quality will apply to the bucket selection as well (even using the dumber and less forgiving AND bit-masking approach to bucket selection).

As you've noticed, this does mean you'll see collisions in the table.  If you can exploit patterns in the keys to get less collisions that this random-but-repeatable quality would give you, then by all means make the most of that.  If not, the beauty of hashing is that with random-but-repeatable hashing your collisions are statistically related to your load factor (the number of stored elements divided by the number of buckets).

As an example, for [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) - when your load factor is 1.0, 1/e　(~36.8%) of buckets will tend to be empty, another 1/e (~36.8%) have one element, 1/(2e) or ~18.4% two elements, 1/(3!e) about 6.1% three elements, 1/(4!e) or ~1.5% four elements, 1/(5!e) ~.3% have five etc.. - the average chain length from non-empty buckets is ~1.58 no matter how many elements are in the table (i.e. whether there are 100 elements and 100 buckets, or 100 million elements and 100 million buckets), which is why we say lookup/insert/erase are O(1) constant time operations.

> I know that hash algorithms are supposed to minimize the same result for different inputs, however I don't understand how the same results for different inputs can be minimal after the modulo operation.

This is still true post-modulo.  Minimising the same result means each post-modulo value has (about) the same number of keys mapping to it.  We're particularly concerned about in-use keys stored in the table, if there's a non-uniform statistical distribution to the use of keys.  With a hash function that exhibits the random-but-repeatable quality, there will be random variation in post-modulo mapping, but overall they'll be close enough to evenly balanced for most practical purposes.

---

Just to recap, let me address this directly:

> Let's just say we have a near-perfect hash function that gives a different hashed value between 0 and 100,000, and then we take the result modulo 20 (in our example we have 20 buckets), isn't the resulting number very close to a random number between 0 and 19? Meaning roughly the probability that the final result is any of a number between 0 and 19 is about 1 in 20? If this is the case, then the original hash function doesn't seem to ensure minimal collisions because after the modulo operation we end up with something like a random number? I must be wrong, but I'm thinking that what ensures minimal collisions the most is not the original hash function but how many buckets we have.

So:

- random is good: if you get something like the random-but-repeatable hash quality, then your average hash collisions will statistically be capped at low levels, and in practice you're unlikely to ever see a particularly horrible collision chain, provided you keep the load factor reasonable (e.g. <= 1.0)
- that said, your "near-perfect hash function...between 0 and 100,000" may or may not be high quality, depending on whether the distribution of values has patterns in it that would produce collisions.  When in doubt about such patterns, use a hash function with the random-but-repeatable quality.

> What would happen if you took a random number instead of using a hash function? Then doing the modulo on it? If you call rand() twice you can get the same number - a proper hash function doesn't do that I guess, or does it? Even hash functions can output the same value for different input.

This comment shows you grappling with the desirability of randomness - hopefully with earlier parts of my answer you're now clear on this, but anyway the point is that randomness is good, but it has to be repeatable: the same key has to produce the same pre-modulo hash so the post-modulo value tells you the bucket it should be in.

As an example of random-but-repeatable, imagine you used `rand()` to populate a `uint32_t a[256][8]` array, you could then hash any 8 byte key (e.g. including e.g. a `double`) by XORing the random numbers:

```
auto h(double d) {
    uint8_t i[8];
    memcpy(i, &d, 8);
    return a[i[0]] ^ a[i[1]] ^ a[i[2]] ^ ... ^ a[i[7]];
}
```

This would produce a near-ideal (`rand()` isn't a great quality pseudo-random number generator) random-but-repeatable hash, but having a hash function that needs to consult largish chunks of memory can easily be slowed down by cache misses.

> Following on from what [Mureinik] said, assuming you have a perfect hash function, say your array/buckets are 75% full, then doing modulo on the hashed function will probably result in a 75% collision probability. If that's true, I thought they were much better. Though I'm only learning about how they work now.

The 75%/75% thing is correct for a high quality hash function, assuming:

- closed hashing / open addressing, where collisions are handled by finding an alternative bucket, or
- separate chaining when 75% of buckets have one or more elements linked therefrom (which is very likely to mean the load factor (which many people may think of when you talk about how "full" the table is) is already significantly more than 75%)

Regarding *"I thought they were much better."* - that's actually quite ok, as evidenced by the percentages of colliding chain lengths mentioned earlier in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right understanding of the situation.

Both the hash function and the number of buckets affect the chance of collisions. Consider, for example, the worst possible hash function - one that returns a constant value. No matter how many buckets you have, all the entries will be lumped to the same bucket, and you'd have a 100% chance of collision.

On the other hand, if you have a (near) perfect hash function, the number of buckets would be the main factor for the chance of collision. If your hash table has only 20 buckets, the minimal chance of collision will indeed be 1 in 20 (over time). If the hash values weren't uniformly spread, you'd have a much higher chance of collision in at least one of the buckets. The more buckets you have, the less chance of collision. On the other hand, having too many buckets will take up more memory (even if they are empty), and ultimately reduce performance, even if there are less collisions.

Comment: What would happen if you took a random number instead of using a hash function? Then  doing the modulo on it? If you call rand() twice you can get the same number - a proper hash function doesn't do that I guess, or does it? Even hash functions can output the same value for different input.

Comment: @Zebrafish if the hash function returns a random number you'd probably break the hash table. The basic requirement of a hash function is that if two objects are logically equal, they should have the same hash. If you randomize the hash, you'll lose this behavior.

Comment: Oh of course. Following on from what you said, assuming you have a perfect hash function, say your array/buckets are 75% full, then doing modulo on the hashed function will probably result in a 75% collision probability. If that's true, I thought they were much better. Though I'm only learning about how they work now.

Comment: @Zebrafish a lot (most?) of the hashtable/hashmap implementations I've seen will rehash when they get too full - i.e., they'll extend the number of buckets (usually double them) and then redistribute the objects in the hashtable across the new buckets. Having said that, it isn't perfect, and if you continue to bombard the hashtable with objects with the same hash code, no amount of rehahsing will help you